# For loop keeps iteratively parsing JSON even after condition is complete

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm putting JSON data into a table view, and I'm trying to parse through the data using a for loop. However, when the loop is done parsing through the JSON data and has placed the 20 items into the table view, it restarts the process, parses the JSON again, and the same data appears in the table view again. This process repeats for a long time as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last else{ return }

    var searchURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50000&types=night_club&key=MY_API_KEY", (location.coordinate.latitude),(location.coordinate.longitude)) as? String

    var cityInfo = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50000&types=locality&key=MY_API_KEY", (location.coordinate.latitude),(location.coordinate.longitude)) as? String

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    getCityInfo(url: cityInfo!)
    callAlamo(url: searchURL!)
}

func getCityInfo(url:String){

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

        self.parseJSON(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

func parseJSON(JSONData:Data){

    do{

        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData) as! JSONStandard

        // PARSING THROUGH JSON DATA TO GET CITY NAME

        if let results = readableJSON["results"] as? [JSONStandard]{
            for i in 0..<results.count{

                let item = results[i]
                let cityInfo = item["name"] as! String
                cityName.append(cityInfo)

                // GETTING PHOTO URL WITH photo_reference AND PUTTING THEM INTO imageURL ARRAY

                if let photos = item["photos"] as? [JSONStandard]{

                    for j in 0..<photos.count{

                        let photo = photos[j] as JSONStandard

                        let photoRef = photo["photo_reference"] as! String

                        let photoURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=%@&key=MY_API_KEY", photoRef) as? String
                        cityURL.append(photoURL!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cityLabel.text = cityName[0]
        cityImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:cityURL[0]), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cityOfCalgary"))
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}

 func callAlamo(url:String){

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}
 func parseData(JSONData:Data){

    do{
        var myReadableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard

        // PARSING THROUGH JSON DATA TO GET NAMES AND PICTURES OF PLACES, THEN PUTTING 
        // THEM INTO AN ARRAY AND OUTPUTTING THEM ONTO TABLE VIEW CELL

        if let results = myReadableJSON["results"] as? [JSONStandard]{

            for i in 0..<results.count{ //results.count = 20

                let item = results[i]
                let names = item["name"] as! String

                placeNames.append(names)

                // GETTING PHOTO URL WITH photo_reference AND PUTTING THEM INTO imageURL ARRAY

                if let photos = item["photos"] as? [JSONStandard]{

                    let photoRef = photos[0]
                    let photoReference = photoRef["photo_reference"] as! String


                    let photoURL = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=%@&key=MY_API_KEY", photoReference) as? String

                    imageURL.append(photoURL!)

                }

                if let geometry = item["geometry"] as? JSONStandard{
                    if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String : Any]{

                            let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double
                            let longitude = location["lng"] as? Double
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                // SHOULD BE PLACED AT THE END OF GATHERING DATA
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As vadian had mentioned in one of his first comments, parseData() was getting called multiple times. So I added

> locationManager.delegate = nil

after I stop updating the location in the locationManager delegate function.

```
 `    

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last else{ return }

    searchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)&radius=50000&types=night_club&key=MY_API_KEY"

    cityInfo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)&radius=50000&types=locality&key=MY_API_KEY"

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.delegate = nil

    getCityInfo(url: cityInfo)
    callAlamo(url: searchURL)
}
```

`

Everything else remains the same after this.

Comment: I guess `parseData` is called twice, the code doesn't repeat in the method. As always `.mutableContainers` is meaningless in Swift, omit the `options` parameter and instead of the ugly C-style index loop use fast enumeration `for item in results`.

Comment: PS: And do not reload the table view in each iteration of the loop. Put the line  – as well as `stopUpdatingLocation()` – **after** the repeat loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and tips. I've updated my code to reflect some of the suggestions you've made, also to show which method is calling parseData. Unfortunately, I am still stuck with the same problem. Let me know if you have anymore suggestions that could help

Comment: ohhh....you are calling callAlamo(url: searchURL!) in didUpdateLocations .which is leads for multiple calls of callAlamo

Comment: Riiiiight. Where would you suggest I make the call to the method?

Comment: You can add stopUpdatingLocation() before callAlamo(url: searchURL!)  and once parsing done add startUpdatingLocation

Comment: I've tried doing that as well, but the same problem persists. I've updated my code, if you'd like to have a look. Maybe it's where I've placed my self.tableView.reloadData?

Comment: want to do small teamviewer session? want to see the bug

Comment: yeah, that would be great. Is it possible to do in StackOverflow?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Thank you all for your advice. I posted the solution under the update.

Comment: You mean you can not debug and check which function is calling your parseJSON twice ?

Comment: I'm still new to iOS programming, so I'm still trying to understand the ropes behind it all. Hence my username, notSoExpereinceCoder.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected you are calling `parseData` multiple times. A solution is to stop monitoring the location right in the delegate method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last else { return }

    let searchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)&radius=50000&types=night_club&key=AIzaSyA2LQsGK_I1ETnKPGbjWgFW9onZlHog6dg"

    // var cityInfo = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50000&types=locality&key=AIzaSyA2LQsGK_I1ETnKPGbjWgFW9onZlHog6dg", (location?.coordinate.latitude)!,(location?.coordinate.longitude)!) as? String
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    callAlamo(url: searchURL)
}
```

I edited the body of the method a bit to avoid all question and exclamation marks.

Side-note: Basically **do not** annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: So I implemented what you had suggested, but the same problem persists =(
I've updated my code